# Could dark matters massive gravity create areas of slowly released expanding space left over from the big bang?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, dark-matter

I am not a physicist and apologize if this wastes anyone's time. I follow progress in most theoretical fields of physics and understand the premises but not how they are realised. The question I posed has been eating at me for a long time (ever since a link between time and gravity was discovered). Some of the other things I have theorized over the years are being considered now and I haven't heard of this concept. Logic would dictate someone with an actual education has already answered this, so again I'm sorry if I waste anyone's time.

Comment: Spelling tip: waist is related to your pant size; waste is use/expend.

Answer (score 4):

It's simple. The answer is no. Dark matter, wherever it is, will contribute to the right hand side stress energy tensor, and will affect spacetime just like any other matter - at least in the large. Since mainly non-interacting, except for gravity and maybe weak field forces, it will mainly act like non interacting dust in the universe. The spacetime it influences, and is influenced by, is just like any other matter dominated spacetime. Yes, it may expand after the Big Bang, but the dark matter is just another type of matter, and it adds to the total matter energy density that tends to slow down the expansion.

Of course it affects galaxy formation and other astrophysical processes because it is there, and unlike normal matter doesn't collide with and thus tend to dissipate energy. Also, because it is there, it's attractive gravitational forces helps form concentrations of matter, like galaxies.

Finally, not clear what slowly released space means, but whatever dark matter is there affects the spacetime just like any other energy concentration, in terms of matter-energy density, and certainly expanded with the inflation and rest of universal expansion. In a simplistic sense, if somehow it just appeared somewhere, it would affect the spacetime at some distance at the local speed of light (= of gravity), c, and it would remain attractive

Answer (score -3):

1. dark matter has not been directly observed, but its presence is implied by for example the gravitational effects that visible matter cannot cause
2. mostly when observing galaxies, without dark matter they would fly away and not rotate
3. dark matter makes up most of the mass in the universe, so to your question yes, those areas where the mass is concentrated (galactic clusters), expanding is not so strong
4. the expanding of space is mostly happening in between of galaxy clusters where there is no mass (and so no dark matter or normal matter either)